# How to add Character Length Min and Max Validation on this Uppercase First Letter for Each Word Regex

Tags: regex, validation, cpu-word, letter

I found [this Regex to validate proper names containing white spaces](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8391340?hl=en) and I like it.

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(\s([A-Z]|\([A-Z])[a-z\'\(\)]*)?((\s|\-)([A-Z]|\([A-Z])[a-z\'\(\)]*)?((\s|\-)([A-Z]|\([A-Z])[a-z\'\(\)]*)?((\s|\-)([A-Z]|\([A-Z])[a-z\'\(\)]*)?$
```

But how if I want to add minimum and maximum length validation? I Expect minimum is 3 and maximum is 25 for all total characters for sample:

Tada Tadadada Tadadadadada (length is 26) is not allowed,
Ta is not allowed,
Tada Tadadada Tadadadadad (length is 25) is allowed,
Tad is allowed

Comment: probably you can't because min and max can set to only one character, you can edit you post and tell how you want the name format to be

Comment: i've given the sample, is it still probable?

Comment: you can do this `^([A-Z][a-z]{2,25})$` this will test for proper name start with upper case letter followed by lower case letters and between 3-25 , if you went to add spaces between multiple names then u shoud make a range for every one of them

Comment: I think Google Forms uses re2. Try `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,24}$` https://regex101.com/r/ag15gM/1

Comment: @Guinglain Did that work out?

Comment: @Thefourthbird & aziz that is working but still need improvement because I expect there is no uppercase along each word except on the first letter each word. For sample, input Gloomy HumbUG this is still accepted and doesn't like what I expect.